# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in header.php

Tags: opencart

I have setup both config file but getting this error on home page.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs******\admin\controller\common\header.php:122

Please help me shootout this issue.

Comment: show your header.php.  $this->customer is null in $this->customer->isLogged.

Comment: It did not work. Now i am getting white screen on home. I am using opencart 1.5.6

Comment: check you error.log file

Comment: Error log is blank!!

Comment: I can see admin login screen but admin login also not working.!

Comment: Please share your site details i will fix it

Comment: Sorry, i am working on Localhost.

Comment: Don't look at Opencarts error log, look at Apache's error log.

Comment: I am getting again 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\limeapple\admin\controller\common\header.php:122

Comment: after using $this->customer admin page is not working.